# How to dual boot Ubuntu and Phoenix OS

Tags: partition, system-installation, grub2, dual-boot, android

I have recently installed [Remix OS](http://www.jide.com/remixos) (A version of Android x86 modded for use on the desktop) alongside Ubuntu 14.04 using [this guide](https://medium.com/@deepakpk/how-to-dual-boot-remixos-with-ubuntu-c7ee2d973f72). It consisted of extracting the files from the ISO, pasting them into a folder at the root, adding a GRUB entry, and that's it! No need for partitioning the HDD...

Now, I heard that [Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/en/download_x86) was better than Remix OS and I would like to try it out. I tried to find a way to install Phoenix OS alongside Ubuntu, but I didn't seem to find anything.

So my question is, how can I dual boot Phoenix OS and Ubuntu? Preferably without needing to partition my HDD...

Comment: Have you tried the exact same guide but changing to Phoenix OS `.iso` file and the name from the `/remix` to `/phoenix`?

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working... Should have occurred to me...

Comment: no problem :) good luck with your phoenix os